# How do I pass a class reference from another class?

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception

I'm building a basic beginner Java program but I keep getting the NullPointerException error and I can't seem to solve the problem.

I have two classes - User and Cart.

The User class includes the Cart class with the following code :

```
package eCommerceApp;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class User extends Person {

    public User(String name, String surname, int budget) {
        super(name, surname, budget);
    }

    public Cart myCart;

    public String getReceipt(List<Product> products) {

        int sum = 0;

        for (Product product : products) {

            sum += product.getPrice();
        }
        return "Your total bill is " + sum + " rsd.";
    }

    public String getMostExpensiveItem(List<Product> products) {

        Product product = Collections.max(products, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getPrice()));

        return "The most expensive item in your shopping cart is " + product.getName() + ".";

    }

    public String getCheapestItem(List<Product> products) {

        Product product = Collections.min(products, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getPrice()));
        return "The cheapest item in your shopping cart is " + product.getName() + ".";

    }

}
```

And the Cart Class :

```
import java.util.List;

public class Cart {

    List<Product> products;

    public Cart(List products) {

        this.products = products;
    }

    public String getProducts() {
        return this.products.toString();
    }

    public void setProducts(List products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

}
```

Now, when I want to set a list of products to my User's Cart by typing **User.myCart.setProducts(list)** in the main class, I get the NullPointerException error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To use classes in other classes, you'll need to make an instance of them like so:

```java
public Cart myCart = new Cart();
```

Unless your entire class is static, this is the way to go. But it is generally not good practice to make your classes static all the time.

Comment: But: you shouldn't routinely make classes full of `static` methods _just_ to avoid the need to create new objects.  Creating new objects and tying them together is the very essence of object-oriented programming.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  1+

Comment: The answer is correct, but the strong insinuation that 'you should just make things static' is such bad advice, this can't be upvoted as is.

Comment: Where should be making that instance call? In the User or main class in my app?

Comment: In this case, in your user class.